# Scaling GUI elements for different resolutions

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up a GUI menu in Unity that will work for all devices. So I started it in setting it up for one resolution that is: 1024 * 600.

It looks ok on that, so I tried adding a scaler to make it look ok on all the rest to.

Example of my code for getting scaler:

```
float originalWidth = 1024;
float originalHeight = 600;     
Vector3 scale;
scale.x = Screen.width/originalWidth; 
scale.y = Screen.height/originalHeight; 
scale.z = 1;
```

Then I resize every element with that scale like that:

```
rect = new Rect(width/2 - 65 * scale.x, height/2 - 50 * scale.y, 130 * scale.x, 65 * scale.y);
```

But it just doesn't look the same.
I also tried like that:

```
rect = new Rect((width/2-65) * scale.x, (height/2-50) * scale.y, 130 * scale.x, 65 * scale.y);
```

but it just looked even more wrong.

So to be clear I would like my element to be in the middle of screen with some offset and look the same on all devices.

The biggest problem is when 2 elements needs to be aligned to each other perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a GUI Matrix at your native GUI resolution...

```
float rx = Screen.width / 1024.0f;
float ry = Screen.height / 600.0f;  
GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(rx, ry, 1));
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.TRS.html

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages of the screen as positions and sizes for GUI elements:

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width*0.40f, Screen.height*0.4f, Screen.width*0.20f, Screen.height*0.20f));
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it's realy hard to position elements in relation to each other, plus it scales images in unusual way...